# How to confirm email using Angular and ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using Angular 9 (localhost:4200) and WebAPI with dotnet Core 3.1 (localhost:5000). During user registration I pass user data from Client to Server and then in Register method I send him an email to verify. After user clicks the link it redirects him to localhost:5000 to VerifyEmail method.

How to create a **link** in Registration function so the code could hit the client function first and then confirm verification on server? 
Or there is better way to confirm email with Angular/dotnet core WebApi?

**Client Side:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { User } from '../_models/user';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
baseUrl = environment.apiUrl + 'auth/';

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

register(user: User) {
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'register', user);
  }
}

verifyEmail(data: any) {     // not used 
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'VerifyEmail', data);
  }
```

**Server Side:**

```
[HttpPost("register")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register(UserForRegisterDto userForRegisterDto)
        {
            var code = string.Empty;
            var userToCreate = _mapper.Map<User>(userForRegisterDto);
            try
            {
                var userExists = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(userToCreate.UserName);
                if (userExists == null)
                {
                    var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(userToCreate, userForRegisterDto.Password);
                    code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(userToCreate);
                    if (result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        //some code
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    var emailConfirmed = await _userManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(userExists);
                    code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(userExists);
                    if (emailConfirmed)
                    {
                        return Ok();
                    }
                }

                var link = Url.Action(nameof(VerifyEmail), "Auth", new { userId = userToCreate.Id, code }, Request.Scheme, Request.Host.ToString());

                await _emailService.SendAsync("test@test.com", "email verify", $"<a href=\"{link}\">Verify Email</a>", true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
            return Ok();
        }

public async Task<IActionResult> VerifyEmail(string userId, string code)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(code))
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);

            if (user == null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            if (user.EmailConfirmed)
            {
                //return Ok();
            }

            var result = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, code);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return Ok();
            }

            return BadRequest();
        }
```

Thank you in advance for any help and your time!

Comment: If I understand correctly you could create a new component in angular that resolves to a route like /verify-email and in its ngOnInit() method add logic to call your verifyEmail method from AuthService

Comment: Thank you, it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd create a new angular component that resolves to /verify-email route and from there called AuthService

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'email-verification',
  template: '<h1>{{status}}</h1>',
  styleUrls: [ './email-verification.component.css' ]
})
export class EmailVerificationComponent implements OnInit  {
  status: string = "Verifying...";
  constructor(private authService: AuthService){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.verifyEmail().subscribe(_ => this.status = "Email verified!");
    //redirect to another component
  }
}
```